# Can't get User.Identity.GetUserId()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've got a simple web application and I can't user `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method. Every time I use it, it returns back null, or 0 if I use `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()`.

For example in this code part.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
```

Please , someone help me with this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? and if so what is the value of `userId` after you step pass this line `var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();` also `AddErrors(result);` should't that be wrapped around an `else{}` statement

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: DJ KRAZE, I've stopped through the code, and as I said , it's gives back 0 or null, depends on what type of value you want it to return.

Comment: Ryan Schlueter, I'm using the default authentication of the web application of MVC, if you was asking for that.

Comment: I would take a look at these two posts my guess eithere authentication or iis issue using annonymous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839567/why-does-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-return-blank http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515890/authentication-issue-when-debugging-in-vs2013-iis-express/

Comment: Authentication mode is set to "Forms"

Comment: I've tried to check whether user is Authenticated or no, but it returned true.

Comment: Authentication mode "Forms" is the problem.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Should be `AuthenticationMode="None"`

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494063/securing-cookies-for-default-mvc-5-application/26496321#26496321 - and update your config.

Comment: @shoe It must be "Form", but even if I change it to "None", nothing happens, and I can't pass the Log in Form.